# Set equivalent of {Binding .} from code behind in Xamain?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, model-binding

I am currently setting a label binding from code behind which works fine as below:

```
lblLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, model.DataField);
```

However I now need to add multiple bindings (model.Title and model.DataField) to the Label so want to bind the entire BindingContext to use in a converter, in XAML I would use:

```
{Binding .}
```

So have tried the following from the code behind but this just passes null to the converter?

```
lblLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".", BindingMode.Default, new ModelToStringConverter());
```

Is this possible to achieve from the code behind or can you only use "." in XAML directly?

Comment: Why not combine model.Title and model.DataField in the ViewModel and then binding to a new property with this value. Then you do not need to use a Converter.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to XAML's `"."` is `this`.

For your scenario, you need the path as a string tho, so you can use `"."` by creating a new `Binding`:

```
ModelToStringConverter modelToStringConverter = new ModelToStringConverter();
txtBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(".", converter: modelToStringConverter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that but get the error " Argument type '...' is not assignable to parameter type 'string' "?

Comment: I see your problem now. `this` is the proper equivalent, but as it's not a `string`, it can't be used here. I'll test is and try to find a solution.

Comment: @Apqu Please see my updated answer and check if this works.